# MongoDB replication or master-slave, How to choose?

Tags: mongodb

I have a local `mongodb` instance for production purposes (PRIMARY) and another `mongodb` instance in cloud system for backup purpose only (SECONDARY). Here's what  I want :

1. User will be able to write/read from PRIMARY instance
2. SECONDARY instance contains copy of PRIMARY, synced every time there are changes in PRIMARY's data
3. If the connection between PRIMARY and SECONDARY is severed, User still able to write/read from PRIMARY instance without any disturbance
4. BONUS: if PRIMARY instance is down, then User will able to write/read directly from SECONDARY instance

I've used replicaSet before, and it is disappointing that whenever PRIMARY instance lost its connection to SECONDARY instance, the User won't be able to write to both instance ([because mongodb election mechanic](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/))

I haven't use master-slave before. Does anyone can help to give suggestion ?

Comment: Master-slave is a deprecated feature of MongoDB. You should always use replica sets for new deployments. If you want high availability for this replica set then I would add a 3rd member or an arbiter. The reason you lose write ability with only 2 members is an event like a network partition could mean you have 2 members up but they can't talk to each-other. If this resulted in 2 primaries you would end up with 2 divergent data sets.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I had to stick with replica set. They way your suggestion says that I will need 2 instances in my local LAN network and another instance as an arbiter. It seems legit, I'll try it soon. thanks

Comment: Replica set with 3 data bearing members would be a best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has chosen for you (: 
Since version 3.6 Master-Slave replication is [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/master-slave/).

Regarding the specific replication deployment (following the discussion in the comments): 
 **Arbiter are usually used when you have an even number of nodes and you need a extra member that could help with the primary election.**  
**If you don't have any cost constraints** I would suggest that you **deploy an additional replica** (to complete an odd number of replicas in the cluster) that can hold data  **instead of an arbiter**.